# How to split a column in R using lower case sensitivity as a factor and look-behind feature

Tags: r, tidyr, gsub

I have a large dataframe in R that is comprised of lower case and uppercase letters in a single column.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c('GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGTcatGGCGTCGC', 'GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGTcatGGCGTCGC', 'TCACCACCATCtCATTCTGC', 'ACTGGTTCCAcCAGCGGGTCACGAC'), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like the output to take all of the 'upper case letters' to the left of any lower case letters; i.e., something similar to a look-behind feature.

For example

GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGTcatGGCGTCGC would become GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT
GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGTcatGGCGTCGC would become GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT
ACTGGTTCCAcCAGCGGGTCACGAC would become ACTGGTTCCA

I am only interested in the upper case characters to the left hand side of the first instance of lower case characters. I would like also for the code to not fall over if there is no instance of lower case.

I have tried looking at: [Splitting strings by case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331078/splitting-strings-by-case)
but i cannot seem to adapt it to look behind for upper case.

I really thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `sub("[acgt].*", "", df1$a)`

Comment: Can you elaborate on `I would like also for the code to not fall over if there is no instance of lower case.`

Comment: Thank you, regarding the lower case... some very rare entries have no lower case:
AATATTCACCACCATCTCATTCT
AATATTCACCACCATCTCATTCTGCATTG

in which case, i would like for it to return an NA for that column; but otherwise if it cannot return an NA then this is not a big issue

Comment: Hey, @PeterT please check the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(a = c('GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGTcatGGCGTCGC', 'GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGTcatGGCGTCGC', 'TCACCACCATCtCATTCTGC', 'ACTGGTTCCAcCAGCGGGTCACGAC', 'BAARA'), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1


df1$a <- str_trim(str_extract(df1$a , "([:upper:]|[:space:]){2,}"))
df1
```

Output:

```
                          a
1 GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT
2      GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT
3               TCACCACCATC
4                ACTGGTTCCA
5                     BAARA    #This one not having any lower case charater from the begining
```

Putting NA, where the string dont have any lower cases charaters.

```
 for (i in 1 :nrow(df1)){  
    if(is.na(str_extract(df1[i,'a'], "([:lower:]|[:space:]){1,}"))) 
       {df1[i,'a'] <- NA}
    else 
       {df1[i,'a'] <- str_trim(str_extract(df1[i,'a'] , "([:upper:]|[:space:]){2,}"))}
     df1[i,'b'] <- df1[i,'a']   
    }
 df1
```

Output:

```
                          a
1 GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT
2      GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT
3               TCACCACCATC
4                ACTGGTTCCA
5                      <NA>
```

Comment: very interesting approach for introduction of NAs--I am wondering how to adjust your script such that it does not override the 'a' column but instead generates a separate column 'b' with the output?

Comment: @PeterT do you want duplicate the column 'a' at the same time with same output ?

Comment: yes, if that is possible; it is so that the original input column is preserved without being overidden by the output

Comment: yes, just simply add `>>df1[i,'b'] <- df1[i,'a']`  After end  of if and before end of loop  .

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I apologize I am new with R, but would you mean like this?

 for (i in 1 :nrow(df1)){  
    if(is.na(str_extract(df1[i,'a'], "([:lower:]|[:space:]){1,}"))) 
       {df1[i,'b'] <- df1[i,'a'] <- NA}
    else 
       {df1[i,'b'] <- df1[i,'a'] <- str_trim(str_extract(df1[i,'a'] , "([:upper:]|[:space:]){2,}"))}
        
    }
 df1

Comment: No worries please check updated code. If my solution helped please mark as useful.

Comment: brilliant, worked like a charm! Thank you so much for your expertise and assistance, it is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
sub("([A-Z]+)[a-z].*", "\\1", df1$a)

# [1] "GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGTatGGCGTCGC"
# [2] "GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGTatGGCGTCGC"     
# [3] "TCACCACCATCCATTCTGC"                
# [4] "ACTGGTTCCACAGCGGGTCACGAC"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` with `[a-z].*` or `[[:lower:]].*` to remove the first lower case letter and everything after.

```
sub("[a-z].*", "", df1$a)
#sub("[[:lower:]].*", "", df1$a) #Alternative
#[1] "GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT" "GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT"     
#[3] "TCACCACCATC"               "ACTGGTTCCA"
```

Set to `NA` where there is no lower case:

```
df1 <- rbind(df1, "ABC")               #Add without lower case
is.na(df1$a) <- !grepl("[a-z]", df1$a) #set NA where no lower case
sub("[a-z].*", "", df1$a)
#[1] "GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT" "GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT"     
#[3] "TCACCACCATC"               "ACTGGTTCCA"               
#[5] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all with a line of code with a positive lookahead regex (capturing everything up to the first lower case), so you don't need to deal with the `NA`'s. Either there is a match or not.

```r
stringr::str_extract(df1$a, ".+?(?=[a-z])")

#[1] "GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT" "GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT"      "TCACCACCATC"              
#[4] "ACTGGTTCCA"                NA
```

To add a new column b with the result as asked in the comments:

```r
df1 |> dplyr::mutate(b = stringr::str_extract(a, ".+?(?=[a-z])"))

#                                      a                         b
# 1 GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGTcatGGCGTCGC GCCTTGATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT
# 2      GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGTcatGGCGTCGC      GATTTTTTGGCGGGGACCGT
# 3                 TCACCACCATCtCATTCTGC               TCACCACCATC
# 4            ACTGGTTCCAcCAGCGGGTCACGAC                ACTGGTTCCA
# 5                                BAARA                      <NA>
```